# Set up FreeBSD machine as router/bridge between a computer and the network

Tags: networking, freebsd, routing

I recently installed and did the initial set ups for a FreeBSD virtual machine. My aim is to utilise it as a router/bridge in a network topology structured as follows: from a PC comes a request for a webpage, that is captured by the FreeBSD router (in order to use DummyNet as a test tool on it) and sent to the Internet. I searched online but wasn't able to find nothing up to date or still available. Do any of you have a guide/tutorial or even tips to follow? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: It is really unclear what is your question. Do you intend to route or intercept packets? Or do intend this router to work as an HTTP proxy?

Comment: There is a section on bridging in the [FreeBSD handbook](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/advanced-networking/#network-bridging).

Comment: @AlexD, I'm sorry for the inconvenience! I intend to route the packets through the virtual machine, since as I read online it's the best way to use dummynet

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks a lot!

Comment: And what is your host system?

Comment: @AlexD if you intend the system on which we created the virtual machine, it's MacOS

Answer (score 0):

MacOS already has own support for DummyNet, run `man dnctl` in a terminal.

Comment: Oh, thank you, I didn't know this. Knowing this, can the network topology change? For instance, instead of using two PCs, one for the webpage request, one for using the dummynet features, can I do it with just one machine?